# Ruby on Rails: collection_select - display something other than text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack, collection-select

On Rails 4. I am building a site where you can search graphics/products according to their assigned color scheme. Relevant models:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base 
  belongs_to :color_scheme
end

class ColorScheme < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :products
end
```

Each color scheme has five color hexadecimal values as columns. Using Bootstrap, here's what the code looks like as a dropdown, without being a `collection_select`:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" 
  data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true" style="width:100%; margin-bottom:20px;">
    <%= t('template.scheme')%> <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <% @color_schemes.where(enabled: true).each do |scheme| %>
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">
        <div style="width:30px; height: 20px; display: inline-block;
          background-color:#<%=scheme.color1%>;"></div>
        <div style="width:30px; height: 20px; display: inline-block;
          background-color:#<%=scheme.color2%>;"></div>
        <div style="width:30px; height: 20px; display: inline-block;
          background-color:#<%=scheme.color3%>;"></div>
        <div style="width:30px; height: 20px; display: inline-block;
          background-color:#<%=scheme.color4%>;"></div>
        <div style="width:30px; height: 20px; display: inline-block;
          background-color:#<%=scheme.color5%>;"></div>
      </li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And this is the visual result:

[image]

Since I'm using Ransack and this is a dropdown for search, I converted this into a `collection_select` but can't figure out how to get that same visual effect.

```
<%= f.collection_select :color_scheme_id_eq, ColorScheme.order('created_at DESC').all, :id, 
  :name, {include_blank: t('template.scheme')}, {class: 'form-control select-scheme', 
  style: 'width:100%; margin-bottom:20px;'} %>
```

So instead of just displaying the color scheme's text name, I'd like to show the colors like above. I understand this is probably outside the scope of what a collection select should be, but I feel the colors make more sense, visually, than the name. Is this possible, either through `collection_select` or some other tag that would work with Ransack? Thanks! Edit: I should also add that I'll probably still have the color scheme's name to the right of the colors, for people who are color-blind, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I have another suggestion:

- create a div which has color scheme above select field
- then use to javascript click event on each color scheme to set value in select field

Here is my code sample to solve this issue:

```
.col-sm-3
  #color-label-project{style: 'text-align: center;'}
    - t('labels.project.label_color_hashes').map do |k, v|
      %span{style: "width:30px; height: 20px; display: inline-block; background-color: #{v};", id: "#{k}", 'data-value': "#{k}"}
  = f.input :label_color, collection: Project::LABEL_COLOR_NAME, prompt: true, disabled: false, label: false

:javascript
  $("#color-label-project span").bind('click', function(){
      $('select[name="project[label_color]"]').val($(this).data("value"));
  })
```

here is my way:

[image]

Comment: I'll take a look at this tonight and will accept it as the answer if this works. This looks great, although I will need to think carefully as this form was also supposed to be on one line. Perhaps I could shift things around or move the div to the left or right to the select. Thank you so much for your help.